# Stuck when I tried to use basic alert inside prompt alert in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, alert

My problem v.simple but I couldn't find the solution. I'm trying to display basic alert inside prompt alert to show my entered result but I don't know why my application stuck.

This is basic example for my code and It's stuck when "Duplicated email" alert displayed and I can't close it when I click on ok button

```
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: 'Replacement Email',
message: "Please enter your new email",
inputs: [{
    type: 'email',
name: 'email',
placeholder: 'user1@gmail.com'
},
],
buttons: [
  {
    text: 'Cancel',
    handler: data => {
      console.log('Cancel clicked');
    }
  },{
    text: 'Save',
    handler: data => { 
      if(data.email!=""){
        if(data.email==this.userService.email){
           let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: "Duplicated email",
              subTitle: "Please enter new email",
              buttons: ['OK']
            });
            alert.present();
         }
      }
    }
  }
]
});
prompt.present();
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @Sampath no errors, my application stuck when second alert displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using "timeout" but I think there is a better solution for this issue

```
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
title: 'Replacement Email',
message: "Please enter your new email",
inputs: [{
    type: 'email',
name: 'email',
placeholder: 'user1@gmail.com'
},
],
buttons: [
  {
    text: 'Cancel',
    handler: data => {
      console.log('Cancel clicked');
    }
  },{
    text: 'Save',
    handler: data => { 
      if(data.email!=""){
        if(data.email==this.userService.email){
           let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: "Duplicated email",
              subTitle: "Please enter new email",
              buttons: ['OK']
            });
            setTimeout(() => {
                alert.present();
            },250);
         }
      }
    }
  }
]
});
prompt.present();
```